Unable to grow vm disk using Cloud-init's growpart and resizefs
I have Ubuntu 20.04 virtual machine server with Cloud-init installed. I am trying to get the vm's disk to be automatically expanded with Cloud-init. The vm host is ESXi and data source is None as I just want to do some automatic configuration for new vms without need for external data source.
I have tried to configure the Cloud-init modules according to this documentation: https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/modules.html#

OS: Ubuntu: 20.04.6 LTS
Cloud-init: 23.4.4-0ubuntu0~20.04.1

Cloud-init is executed on boot but modules growpart and resizefs are always skipped for uknown reason:
2024-04-03 11:59:04,058 - modules.py[DEBUG]: Running module growpart (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_growpart' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_growpart.py'>) with frequency always
2024-04-03 11:59:04,058 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: start: init-network/config-growpart: running config-growpart with frequency always
2024-04-03 11:59:04,058 - helpers.py[DEBUG]: Running config-growpart using lock (<cloudinit.helpers.DummyLock object at 0x7f8bec612430>)
2024-04-03 11:59:04,059 - cc_growpart.py[DEBUG]: growpart disabled: mode=off
2024-04-03 11:59:04,059 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: init-network/config-growpart: SUCCESS: config-growpart ran successfully
2024-04-03 11:59:04,059 - modules.py[DEBUG]: Running module resizefs (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_resizefs' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_resizefs.py'>) with frequency always
2024-04-03 11:59:04,059 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: start: init-network/config-resizefs: running config-resizefs with frequency always
2024-04-03 11:59:04,059 - helpers.py[DEBUG]: Running config-resizefs using lock (<cloudinit.helpers.DummyLock object at 0x7f8bec612460>)
2024-04-03 11:59:04,059 - cc_resizefs.py[DEBUG]: Skipping module named resizefs, resizing disabled
2024-04-03 11:59:04,059 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: init-network/config-resizefs: SUCCESS: config-resizefs ran successfully

I have minimal config at /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg:
cloud_init_modules:
  - growpart
  - resizefs

growpart:
  mode: auto
  devices: ["/"]

resize_rootfs: true

system_info:
  distro: ubuntu
  paths:
    cloud_dir: /var/lib/cloud/
    templates_dir: /etc/cloud/templates/

Partitions and filesystem are at this state during boot:
user@server:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

GPT PMBR size mismatch (20971519 != 31457279) will be corrected by write.
The backup GPT table is not on the end of the device. This problem will be corrected by write.

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 15 GiB, 16106127360 bytes, 31457280 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Device     Start      End  Sectors Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048     4095     2048   1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2   4096 20969471 20965376  10G Linux filesystem

user@server:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       9.8G  3.4G  6.0G  36% /

According to the documentation a file could block growpart but the blocker file does not exist:
user@server:~$ ls /etc/growroot-disabled
ls: cannot access '/etc/growroot-disabled': No such file or directory

What could be causing the modules to be skipped and what should I do to make them work?
UPDATE:
According to cloud-init query the setting from my cloud.cfg is not applied:
user@server:~$ sudo cloud-init query combined_cloud_config

...
  "cloud_init_modules": [
    "growpart",
    "resizefs"
  ],
...
 "growpart": {
    "mode": "off"
  },
...
 "final_message": "This comes from cloud.cfg as it should.",
...

Cloud.cfg seems to be working for other settings as for example final message appears as they are set in the config file.

Command cloud-init query combined_cloud_config suggested in this answer led me to the cause of the problem.
The out put had line like this:
userdata_raw: "#cloud-config\ngrowpart: {mode: 'off'}\nlocale: en_GB.UTF-8\npreserve_hostname:\...

This came from file /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-installer.cfg which had been left over from earlier version of the image. After removing this file which had unwanted configurations module growpart got enabled on boot and partitions and filesystem got expanded like they should.

Per your log, it looks like growpart.mode is set to off, instructing growpart to noop.
You wrote /etc/cloud/cloud.cgf in the question, is this a typo? If yes, your config won't be read.
Could you please run cloud-init query combined_cloud_config and check that growpart.mode is set to auto?
If this does not help. Could you please report an issue attaching the logs?

I had indeed typo in my question. In server the file is cloud.cfg. Fixed this in the question now.
I also updated my question with results from cloud-init query.
I will raise an issue later if I can't find solution to this soon.
